# Double Integral with Change of Variables for xy

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I'm a little stuck on a practice problem. In general, I know the steps, but I must be getting hung up somewhere, as I am not getting the same answer. Here is the problem:

$\iint_{D} xy dA$

Where D is the region bounded by the lines $y=x$, $y=x+4$, $x=0$ and $x=2$.Use the change of variables: $x=2u$ and y=2u$.

My first step is to draw the region. I won't put that here, but it ends up being a parallelogram. So I then use the transformations to find the Jacobian:

$\frac{dx}{du} \frac{dy}{dv} - \frac{dx}{dv} \frac{dy}{du} = 4$

Taking the partials for each I get (2*2) - 0, thus, 4. Then I need to figure out what my new equation will be using the transformations:

$xy \rightarrow (2u)(2u+4) = 4u^2+8uv $

So, I now have:

$\iint_{D*} (4u^2+8uv)4 du dv$

Now, I need to find my D* (new areas of integration). Using the transformation given, I translate the old areas into new:

$y=x \rightarrow 2u+v = 2u \rightarrow v=0$

$y=x+4 \rightarrow 2(2u+v) \rightarrow  v=4$

$x=0 \rightarrow 2u=0 \rightarrow u=0$

$x=2 \rightarrow 2u=2 \rightarrow u=1$

So, this should result in limits of integration for v from 0 to 4 and for u from 0 to 1. Therefore, I should have the final integral to solve as begin:

$\int_0^4 \int_0^1 (4u^2+8uv)4 du dv$

However, when I solve this, I don't get the proper answer. I need to answer it in a decimal form, and that given answer is 26.6667. Where am I going wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The suggested change of variables is incorrect. It should be
$$x=2u,\quad y=2u+4v\qquad(0\leq u\leq1,\ 0\leq v\leq 1)\ .$$
Inspecting the figure one recognizes that for fixed $u\in[0,1]$ one obtains a constant $x\in[0,2]$, and when then $v$ moves from $0$ to $1$ the point $(x,y)$ moves vertically upwards in the drawn parallelogram, starting and ending and the desired $y$-values.

The Jacobian determinant then computes to $8$, and one has $\>x\,y=4u^2+8uv$. We therefore obtain
$$\int_D x\,y\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_0^1\int_0^1 (4u^2+8uv)\>8\>dv\>du={80\over3}\ .$$

Comment: Ah, got it. I must have copied down the suggested change of variables incorrectly. This makes sense. Thank you for catching that!